# pytest Logging File Handler Not Set

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, pytest

I have a Python method in a package I am creating that creates a logging object. The code for that method is as follows.

```
import logging
import os
def get_logger(file = None, level="DEBUG"):
    logFileName = ""
    if file:
        logFileName = file
    else:
        logFileName = f"{os.getcwd()}/logging.log" #test where CWD is when running in zena

    logging.basicConfig(format = '%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                        handlers=[
                            logging.FileHandler(logFileName),
                            logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
                        ])
    logger = logging.getLogger("root")
    logger.setLevel(level)
    return logger
```

And I have a pytest written for this `get_logger()` method

```
from common_functions import common_functions as app
import os
def test_get_logger_no_file_provided(caplog):
    #test log file creation w/ no file path provided
    file = f"{os.getcwd()}/logging.log"
    if os.path.exists(file):
        os.remove(file)

    #test logging to log file w/ no file provided
    
    logger = app.get_logger()
    assert(os.path.exists(file))
    origSize = os.path.getsize(file)
    logger.warning("Test logging statement for size")
    newSize = os.path.getsize(file)
    assert 'Test logging statement for size' in caplog.text #check to make sure logger worked
    assert(origSize != newSize) #check to make sure logger wrote to file
    os.remove(file)
```

Basically what I am trying to do is check that the logger created in `get_logger()` actually writes to a log file. This method works when I run it outside pytest. Is there something that I am missing for setting a file handler for a logger when running code using pytest? The test fails on the final `assert`.

If I debug this code, I see that the logger object file handler is set to `\\\\.\\nul` for the `baseFileName`.

Comment: 0

I'm having the same settings:

logging.FileHandler(log_file_path), logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)

and the same test which fails. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same settings:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    logging.FileHandler(log_file_path),
    logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
)
```

I changed them to:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("my-logger")
logger.setLevel(loglevel)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(log_file_path))
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
```

Now my tests are working again. I assume pytest also has some loggers which might conflict.